# Node-MySQL unable to insert TIME

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, sql-insert

I am trying to build an API in Express.JS with an MySQL-Server running in the background. One of the tables contains a column with a type of **TIME**. When trying to insert into that table however, I get **{code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR', errno: 1064, sqlState: '42000'}**

Using a single ?, the message is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'\'23:00:41\'\' at line 1

Using a double ??, the message is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'`23:00:41`\' at line 1

The actual lines of code look like that:

```
let query = "INSERT INTO Zeiterfassung (Break_Start) VALUES ? ";
let data = Break_Start; //Break_Start is a string like "23:40:39"
dbConn.query(query, data, (err, rows) => {...});
```

MySQL-Version: *8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.2*

Node-Version: *v10.19.0*

Comment: Please don't tag `SQL Server` for a `MySQL` question - they are quite different RDBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a string parameter, then you need to surround the `?` with parentheses:

```
let query = "INSERT INTO Zeiterfassung (Break_Start) VALUES (?)";
dbConn.query(query, [ Break_Start ], function(err, rows) => {...});
```

The syntax with a single `?` without parentheses is meant to pass objects.